# Does Django have `__not_equal`?

Tags: python, django, orm

Does Django have a field lookup like `__not_equal`? (Field lookups are `__exact`, `__contains`, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use one of `__exact`, `__contains` etc. with [`exclude()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/#exclude-kwargs) instead of `filter()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the [`Q` object](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) and negate it.

E.g.

```
Poll.objects.filter(~Q(question='Who'))
```